# Writing a file with properties from the datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, csv

I want a comma-separated list of all the email addresses my application stores. It's too large for a regular request and writing it to the blobstore is also a too large request:

```
class CSVHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        entities = Entity.all().fetch(10000)
        s = ''
        for entity in entities:
            s= s+","+str(entity.email)       
        file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream')     
        with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
          f.write(s)    
        files.finalize(file_name)    
        blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
```

Can I do it as a task, a queue, a backend or something else instead?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to save the entire file in a single write operation, write it to the blobstore in chunks. Using the `csv` module will make this easier, allowing you to write it progressively.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But 1) How do I partition the data? and 2) Could you send some example code how I should use the CSV module? I don't understand how to do output in chunks.

Comment: @Nicke Just break the long string into several smaller strings and write them independently. Or read the docs on the `csv` module in the Python documentation - just pass it the file direclty.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and the comments. This time for a quick solution I just synced my entities with MySQL using the tool approcket that worked with python 2.7 nearly unmodified so now I have a convenient Excel file with all my text data 2008-2011 :-) I might also be even more lucky if Google adds easy backup and export functions to the datastore console so I won't have to program this.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the built-in [bulkloader tool](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html), which can download all objects via the remote API and save selected fields into CSV format.

Comment: I thought so too so I tried it and it didn't work for me. I suppose I should inspect my project configuration.